# Github action npm publish use tag name

Tags: npm, github-actions, npm-publish, npm-version

I'm migrating our existing Travis tasks to GH actions. For Travis the command below would publish to npm and use the release tag name for the npm version.

```
script: yarn npm-bundle && npm version $TRAVIS_BRANCH --allow-same-version -m
      "chore - release version %s [skip ci]" --allow-empty
```

Unfortunately changing to the below doesn't work...

```
        run: |
          yarn npm-bundle && npm version ${{ github.event.release.tag_name }} --allow-same-version -m "chore - release version %s [skip ci]" --allow-empty
          npm publish --access public --dry-run
```

Its obviously empty as npm is using the version from package.json. I've tried some other variables such as `${{ github.head_ref }}`

also...

```
run: |
          yarn npm-bundle -m "chore - release version %s [skip ci]" --allow-empty
          npm publish --tag ${{ github.event.release.tag_name }} --allow-same-version --access public --dry-run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by refactoring to the following...

```
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.15.0
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: yarn install
      - run: git config --global user.name "${{ github.actor }}"
      - run: git config --global user.email "github-action-${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com"
      - run: npm version ${{ github.event.release.tag_name }}
      - run: yarn npm-bundle
      - run: npm publish --access public
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [npm-publish](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/npm-publish) action in your workflow instead of the script you used in Travis.

If you look for more actions available with NPM, you can find them on thee [Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=npm+publish+)

For example here, you could use something like this in your workflow, adapting in with your context with other `run` step if you need to use `yarn` or other commands:

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test
      - uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          tag: <your release tag name>
```

For more information regarding how this action work, [check here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/npm-publish#github-action).

#### Other Action

This [other action (publish-to-npm)](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-to-npm) could be interesting as well if you want to check.